# avoid the SQL injection in like query in Android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I tried to make a search method in my SQLite database using the fallowing

```
    Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(
                "SELECT *  FROM "
                        + TableInformation.TABLE_NAME
                        + " LEFT OUTER JOIN "
                        + FavouritesItems.TableInformation.TABLE_NAME
                        + " ON "
                        + FavouritesItems.TableInformation.TABLE_NAME + "." + FavouritesItems.TableInformation.FAVOURITE_ITEM_ID
                        + " = "
                        + TableInformation.TABLE_NAME + "." + TableInformation.ITEM_ID
                        + " WHERE 1 = 1"
                        + (itemSearch.getItemDescription().length() > 0 ? " AND " + TableInformation.ITEM_DESCRIPTION + " LIKE %" + "?" + "% " : "")
                        + (itemSearch.getItemDescriptionEn().length() > 0 ? " AND " + TableInformation.ITEM_DESCRIPTION_EN + " LIKE '%" + "?" + "%' " : "")
                       , mySQLStatementStrings);
```

but when i compile it throws the fallowing exception Because the compiler cant find the question mark in like statement '%?%'

```
    FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.shamisoft.myjewelaryshopproject, PID: 18398
                                                                                 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot bind argument at index 1 because the index is out of range.  The statement has 0 parameters.
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bind(SQLiteProgram.java:212)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindString(SQLiteProgram.java:166)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.bindAllArgsAsStrings(SQLiteProgram.java:200)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:47)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
                                                                                     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1255)
                                                                                     at com.shamisoft.myjewelaryshopproject.classes.Items.getItemsSearch2(Items.java:705)
                                                                                     at com.shamisoft.myjewelaryshopproject.classes.SearchItemCustomDialog$1.onClick(SearchItemCustomDialog.java:103)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4781)
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19874)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:902)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:697)
```

the question is how to avoid the SQL injection in this case ???

Comment: You have to add a `?` to show where it adds the arguments. You pass one argument but have no places to add those, hence it throws an exception

Comment: the ? mark is here  after like word 

(itemSearch.getItemDescription().length() > 0 ? " AND " + TableInformation.ITEM_DESCRIPTION + " LIKE %" + "?" + "% " : "")

Comment: Now I realize that isn't the problem. The problem is the poorly formed SQL query. `> 0 ?` is not a good SQL query (or a valid one for that matter)

Comment: the sql statement works good but the problem appears ONLY when the user write ' in the edit text

Comment: try removing the % from the query and place them in mySQLStatementStrings

Comment: You should also remove the '  so:[ LIKE '%" + "?" + "%']   becomes [LIKE ?]  then in your mySQLStatementStrings eg {"%"+"test"+"%", "%"+"test2"+"%"}

Comment: it works when i plase the '% in the mySQLStatementStrings
thank you meeeee :)

Comment: `avoid the SQL injection ...` -> First of all, remove `+ "WHERE 1 = 1"` **immediately**. That's the **main door** for SQL injections.

Answer (score 2):

Inside a string, a `?` is just a normal character.

A string value to be used as a parameters ends up as a separate string value in SQL. If needed, you can then combine if with other strings:

```
... WHERE ...
      AND (Description    LIKE '%' || ? || '%' OR
           Description_EN LIKE '%' || ? || '%')
```

Comment: I've searched fo an answer to this periodically over the years, and never found one. It makes sense once you point out the answer, but I never thought of it that way. Thanks so much.